# SQL Query - is there a way to ascending id number which has same value?

Tags: sql

I want to know if there is a way to repeating ascending if id number has a same value??

the details :

let say I have a value of id like this:

```
|-----|
| id  |
|-----|
|  1  |
|  1  |
|  2  |
|  3  |
|  3  |
|  4  |
|  5  |
|  2  |
|  4  |
|  5  |
|-----|
```

then I want to ascending that id like this :

```
|-----|
| id  |
|-----|
|  1  |
|  2  |
|  3  |
|  4  |
|  5  |
|  1  |
|  2  |
|  3  |
|  4  |
|  5  |
|-----|
```

I don't know how to say that, also don't know the `keyword` to find it on google, so I hope my question is usefull for everyone in case had a same issue.

Comment: We need more information about your intent. What is the actual data you're processing?

Comment: Also, remember that SQL and relational-algebra is concerned with is filtering and joining related data, the ability to sort data is considered a "view" concern, which is why SQL doesn't provide very powerful sorting and row-numbering capabilities, for those you need platform-specific extensions (like `ORDER BY OVER` in SQL Server and PostgreSQL)

Comment: i have a `ask`, `id`, and `answer` column, so every time user insert a new answer, the `id` of `ask` is repeating to insert, so, i need to ascending the `id` of `ask` like that,

Comment: "the id of ask is repeating to insert" - what does that mean?

Comment: instead of `order by id` you need something like `order by ask,id` (I can't work it out from your comment but that's the idea - try it). If you troubled to show the data in the other columns it would be more obvious.

Comment: i dunno how to make it good to typing and let you know, but my issue is like that above, i've try to use `order by` query to `ASC` the id, but the sequence of id gonna be like `1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5`

Comment: Are there more columns in your table? show them please (and their values) Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it's too hard to explain the column by typing here, because i have too much relation in my database, so i thought i just need to show the main issue

Comment: @dondo what does the `ask` column contain? is it an id? Does `ask` and `id` uniquely identify an answer?

Comment: Based on your sample data there isn't a way to do what you want - you need another column to sort on. You've mentioned other columns - again try ordering by a different column _first_

Comment: @GurV the `ask` column just an output to displaying the question in my app, but the answer is the value i need to put in database, and in my app, you can skip the first question to the next question, so my `id`, `ask`, `answer` column value is untidy

Answer (score 2):

In ANSI standard SQL, you can use `row_number()` for this purpose:

```
select id
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by seqnum, id;
```

To be honest, the subquery is not necessary, so you can do:

```
select id
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by id order by id), id;
```

Comment: Dang, you beat me to it! Note to the OP: `OVER( PARTITION BY ...` is not supported by all database systems.

Comment: @Dai . . . It is standard SQL and hence appropriate (in my opinion) for a question that has the SQL tag with no other databases mentioned.

Comment: I mentioned it because the OP did not mention which system he was using.

Comment: It is not going to produce a stable order. Besides, OP hasn't provided sufficient information (though there is some discussion going on about the some other id based on which and the already given id, ordering can be done). Nice idea though.